# How to tie a rope to both sides without loosing its grip strength?

Tags: rope-knots

[image: asda]

I already tried other kinds of ties but nothing seems to accomplish what I want to do.

I tried taut-line hitch, didn't work... the only way to tighten it is to pull the tied part and if apply force at the middle of the rope then It will just simply loosen..

Answer (score 2):

There are several variants of hitches that allow tightening after they are tied.  The most common is the *[taut-line hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch)*.

*Wikipedia* [citing more authoritative sources]

Comment: However, note that some sag is _very_ hard to eliminate, especially over time -- rope will stretch over time.

Comment: @keshlam Very true. The benefit of the taut-hitch type knots is that they can be fairly easily retightened over time without retying.

Comment: BoyScouts use taut line very easy to tighten. A truckers hitch will let you make it tighter.

Comment: @EdBeal Good point. But a truckers hitch needs a secondary tie off point for the tensioning end of the line, like a cleat or a point to make a clove hitch. It might work, depending on the OP's setup. Why not discuss a truckers hitch in an answer?

Comment: a timber hitch on the opposite end from the taut line works pretty well

Comment: I tried taut-line hitch, didn't work... the only way to tighten it is to pull the tied part and if apply force at the middle of the rope then It will just simply loosen..

Comment: I'd like to throw in a vote for the Trucker's Hitch, especially if it's finished off with a Round Turn -> Rolling Hitch and a Half-Hitch on a Bight since any sag can be easily tightened. I'd like to point out that I've only used this with paracord and bank line, [here's a great tutorial for that Trucker's Hitch](https://youtu.be/h62409RbWgY?t=95)

Answer (score 1):

The [Taut Line Hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch) and the [Trucker's Hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trucker%27s_hitch) are the most commonly used knot for this purpose.

If the taut line is slipping, make sure you tied the half hitch at the end in the proper direction. Also make sure you tightened the knot down enough. If it's still slipping, throw in a third turn on the inside and/or a half hitch on the outside.

Alternatively, you could use a [Siberian Hitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_hitch) on one end, and the knot shown in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Mw3lL-ofBcE) at 0:19 in (which I haven't been able to positively id yet). These have the advantage of being quick release.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting a Manila rope soaking wet tying it as tight as you can and then wait for it to shrink as it dries?